# Internet Explorer 9 duplicates in my favourites bar

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-9

Internet Explorer 9 duplicates my favourites in the Favourites Bar. Each time I delete them they reappear.
How can I stop this from happening?

Comment: I noticed you tried to edit my answer but it got denied by moderators. Is the `Add Comment` link below my answer not available for you?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why this is happening but you can physically find the Favorites files in this folder on Windows 7:

```
C:\Users\YOURUSERNAME\Favorites
```

Just make sure to close IE9, then go to the folder, and delete what you need.

If the Favorites still get duplicated when you open IE9 then try running it without add-ons. You might have to uninstall/re-install it completely or even move to IE10 or 11

Many, many options here so let me know if none of these suggestions work.